# QML How could i set default option to null of combobox?

Tags: qt, qml

My combobox like this:

[image]

but i want this:

[image]

My combobox default is first currentText,but i don not want it show any thing when i have not pitch on noting.
if i set:

```
displayText: " "
```

It doesn't work which one I choose.
the value is null.
what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an empty option, put an empty string in your model:

```
ComboBox {
    model: [
        "",
        "During transport",
        "Before cutting",
        "During cutting",
        "After cutting"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set `currentIndex: -1`:

```
ComboBox {
    currentIndex: -1
    model: [ ... ]      
}
```

Note: if it user be able to place own text put `editable: true`